# django test client returns 404, but works in the shell

Tags: django, django-tests

This code works fine in the shell, but if you run it through `python manage.py test` it throws a 404 error, what could be the problem?

test_urls.py

```
from django.test import Client, TestCase


class StaticURLTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.guest_client = Client()

    def test_homepage(self):
        response = self.guest_client.get("/")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

error:

```
❯ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_homepage (posts.tests.test_urls.StaticURLTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/finegorko/Development/Yandex.Practicum/hw03_forms/yatube/posts/tests/test_urls.py", line 10, in test_homepage
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: First there is a typo here `response = self.guest_clientw.get("/")` (the `w`). What do you mean runs fine in shell?

Comment: i mean [it](https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TPV9DP0N4-F03QKASQAF8/image.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a test database was being created that did not have a group.
In `views.py` an object with the function `get_object_or_404()` was passed to the index context.

```
def index(request):
    ...
    group = get_object_or_404(Group) # <--
```